# Why take user all the way to App store to rate an app?

Tags: iphone, applications, ratings, apple

Recently being annoyed by apps asking to rate them in the App store this question came to my mind . Though I am willing to rate the app I don't want to navigate to the app store and then wait for stuff to load up . Why not provide user a form within the app to rate it ?

Something like this :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvIdqZ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

(Circles are stars in disguise)

Is there a drawback to this approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple want to make sure that people don't rate apps multiple times.  When you are using an app, you aren't necessarily signed in or authenticated on Apple's system.  Forcing you to rate the app in an environment where you have to sign in, is a simple way to limit vote manipulation.

Additionally, if Apple did it via an API that apps could use, there is little stopping an app from sending through better ratings that a user gave, and therefore manipulating the voting system.

**TL;DR: Apple are trying to prevent vote manipulation**

Comment: TSDR : Too short did read

Comment: An API might be possible using encryption. eg. calling `getUserRating()` returning an encrypted/hashed string then sending this to the server.